# Utilities to convert folder of static resources to embedded objective-c byte arrays?

Tags: objective-c, ios, static-libraries

We're using static libraries in an iOS app.

Some of those static libraries require bundle resources.

I don't want to distribute those bundle resources as stand-alone files - I want them to be packaged with the static libraries they belong to.

So, I'm looking for a utility/script which can be integrated into the Xcode build process which gets pointed at a folder and automatically updates an auto-generated Objective-C class which allows me to retrieve the contents as a byte array (or whatever) of these resources - which will be built into the static library.

Does anyone already have this? I can't find anything. Obviously I can make it myself if I need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know any ready to use utility that works with directories. But for single file it is trivial enough:

```
cat input_file | ( echo "unsigned char my_data[] = {"; xxd -i; echo "};" ) > output_file.c
```

It will produce file with `my_data` array containing your data. I think it would be easy to extend it to handle directories.

Comment: +1 yeah, I think my question may be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945869/what-clever-solutions-are-there-for-including-resources-in-a-static-lib which has a (much less elegant) bash script to do it. I'm pretty much done with an app to do it for me - I think I'll probably throw it up on the mac app store as a freebie.

Comment: @Steve, yeah my version is MUCH less elegant, that's why I make no profession to know what I'm doing with bash. This version is much better. Use it instead. Maybe sometime I'll update my answer you cited to follow suit.

Comment: @MattWilding - Hey, I wasn't complaining! LOL... Just sayin'. I always figured they named it "bash" because that's what you're doing with your head against your desk by the time you're done figuring it out!

Comment: @Steve, and I'm just happy to simplify my script monolith =)